# Permission denied opening socket / connection with rsync in OpenBSD

Tags: permissions, tcp, openbsd

I recently was trying to retrieve a copy of UCE (spam) sender IPs from uceprotect.net with rsync, but I encountered the following errors:

```
[user@host ucedata]$ rsync -rzv rsync-mirrors.uceprotect.net::RBLDNSD-ALL/ ./                                                                                                                                                            
rsync: failed to connect to rsync-mirrors.uceprotect.net (67.58.96.162): Permission denied (13)                                                                                                                                             
rsync: failed to connect to rsync-mirrors.uceprotect.net (69.30.193.210): Permission denied (13)                                                                                                                                            
rsync: failed to connect to rsync-mirrors.uceprotect.net (72.13.86.154): Permission denied (13)                                                                                                                                             
rsync: failed to connect to rsync-mirrors.uceprotect.net (88.198.110.110): Permission denied (13)                                                                                                                                           
rsync: failed to connect to rsync-mirrors.uceprotect.net (96.31.84.20): Permission denied (13)                                                                                                                                              
rsync: failed to connect to rsync-mirrors.uceprotect.net (185.248.148.6): Permission denied (13)                                                                                                                                            
rsync: failed to connect to rsync-mirrors.uceprotect.net (193.138.29.11): Permission denied (13)                                                                                                                                            
rsync: failed to connect to rsync-mirrors.uceprotect.net (199.48.69.42): Permission denied (13)                                                                                                                                             
rsync: failed to connect to rsync-mirrors.uceprotect.net (199.187.241.194): Permission denied (13)                                                                                                                                          
rsync: failed to connect to rsync-mirrors.uceprotect.net (209.44.102.199): Permission denied (13)                                                                                                                                           
rsync: failed to connect to rsync-mirrors.uceprotect.net (209.126.213.95): Permission denied (13)                                                                                                                                           
rsync: failed to connect to rsync-mirrors.uceprotect.net (217.23.49.207): Permission denied (13)                                                                                                                                            
rsync: failed to connect to rsync-mirrors.uceprotect.net (41.208.71.58): Permission denied (13)                                                                                                                                             
rsync: failed to connect to rsync-mirrors.uceprotect.net (66.240.236.50): Permission denied (13)                                                                                                                                            
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(127) [Receiver=3.1.3]
```

I am able to write to the current directory; why is "permission denied (13)"?

Answer (score 0):

At first, I thought this might be due to some other user permission or user limit.  However, the answer to this particular issue on my particular system was straightforward -- OpenBSD PF was configured to block all outgoing traffic that was not destined to ports 53, 80, 123, or 443.  Because of the loaded PF rules, OpenBSD did not allow the TCP socket to be created in the first place.

Testing with netcat shows that neither the user nor root were able to create a socket with the PF forbidden destination:

```
[user@host ucedata]$ nc -v 67.58.96.162 873
nc: connect to 67.58.96.162 port 873 (tcp) failed: Permission denied
[root@host ucedata]# nc -v 67.58.96.162 873
nc: connect to 67.58.96.162 port 873 (tcp) failed: Permission denied
```

The following kernel trace excerpt shows that the denial of permission is due to attempting the connection:

```
 70602 rsync    CALL  connect(3,0xccece01e770,16)
 70602 rsync    STRU  struct sockaddr { AF_INET, 69.30.193.210:873 }
 70602 rsync    RET   connect -1 errno 13 Permission denied
```

By adding `pass out log on $ext_if proto tcp to any port 873` to `/etc/pf.conf` and reloading the firewall rules (`pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf`), I was then able to connect.